# Use a custom comparator in a class that inherits from std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, inheritance, priority-queue, functor

I've nedded to find elements in a pryority_queue so I created the class:

```
template < typename T >

class AStarPryorityQueue : public std::priority_queue < T, std::vector < T > >{ 

public:
    bool find(const T& value) {
        auto it = std::find(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), value);
        if (it != this->c.end()){return true;}
        else {return false;}
    }
};
```

But I also need to pass a functor used to sort this.The Funtor is:

```
    class LessThanByHeuristic{
        public:
            LessThanByHeuristic(int dest,AStarHeuristic* heuristic,int mapWidth,bool reverse):
            destTile(dest),heuristic(heuristic),tileMapWidth(mapWidth),reverse(reverse){}
            bool operator()(const std::pair<double,int> lhs,const std::pair<double,int> rhs) const{
                if(reverse){
                    return lhs.first + (*heuristic)(Vec2(lhs.second / tileMapWidth,lhs.second % tileMapWidth),
                                                Vec2(destTile / tileMapWidth,destTile % tileMapWidth)) > 
                            rhs.first + (*heuristic)(Vec2(rhs.second / tileMapWidth,rhs.second % tileMapWidth),
                                                Vec2(destTile / tileMapWidth,destTile % tileMapWidth));
                }
                else{
                    return lhs.first + (*heuristic)(Vec2(lhs.second / tileMapWidth,lhs.second % tileMapWidth),
                                                Vec2(destTile / tileMapWidth,destTile % tileMapWidth)) < 
                            rhs.first + (*heuristic)(Vec2(rhs.second / tileMapWidth,rhs.second % tileMapWidth),
                                                Vec2(destTile / tileMapWidth,destTile % tileMapWidth));
                }
            }

        private:
            int destTile;
            AStarHeuristic* heuristic;
            int tileMapWidth;
            bool reverse;
    };
```

How do I create a AStarPryorityQueue passing the functor and his arguments?

Without inheritance I do:

```
typedef std::priority_queue<std::pair<double,int>,std::vector<std::pair<double,int> >,LessThanByHeuristic>  mypqType;
```

and then:

```
mypqType processHeap(LessThanByHeuristic(destTile,heuristic,mapWidth,true));
```

How can I do it now with my AStarPryorityQueue class?

Comment: `std::priority_queue`, as all STL containers and adapters, is not meant to be inherited from (in facts it doesn't have a `virtual` destructor).

Answer (score 0):

The comparator is part of the `priority_queue`'s type, thus you need to specify it in your inheritance declaration:

```
class AStarPryorityQueue : public std::priority_queue <std::pair<double,int>, std::vector<std::pair<double,int>>, LessThanByHeuristic>
```

and in your constructor, since your LessThanByHeuristic isn't default-constructible, you need to call the constructor of std::priority-queue:

```
AStarPryorityQueue(int destTile, AStarHeuristic* heuristic, int tileMapWidth, bool reverse) : std::priority_queue <std::pair<double,int>,std::vector < std::pair<double,int>>,LessThanByHeuristic>{LessThanByHeuristic{destTile, heuristic, tileMapWidth, reverse}}
...
```

EDIT: I'm not 100% sure that's actually what you want to do - for an implementation of A*, you normally need an *addressable priority queue* where you can decrease the key of an already existing entry in the PQ.